# Being informed of new exploits

Tags: wordpress, security, metasploit

Is there any free/opensource repository or service for being informed of new exploits as soon as they are discovered ?
We are using a WP site.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not exactly what you are asking for but I would recommend installing WordFence plugin ( https://www.wordfence.com/ ) as an additional layer of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a cron job for your relevant terms with searchsploit

Check the following links:
[Searchsploit Manual](https://www.exploit-db.com/searchsploit)
[Exploit DB GitHub](https://github.com/offensive-security/exploitdb)